# I want to apply the user defined function row wise

Tags: python, pandas

I want to apply the user-defined function row-wise and skip that whole row if it matches right now I am able to apply overtaking the whole column but how can I pass each row and skip the whole row where it not matches
here is mine code  where I can apply the over each column

```
def name(x):
    x=x.title()                              # title the string
    res=pos_tag(word_tokenize(x))            #tokenizing 
    arr_Val=[]                               # storing each word in this array
    #exceptionList=['Healthcare','Lerner']    # exception list .. MUST UPDATE HERE !!!!
    exc_list=['Mackesson Inc','Care','Healthcare','Henery Schien','Besse','LLC','CandP','INC','LTD','PHARMACY']
    exceptionList = [x.title() for x in exc_list]

    for i in range( len (res)):              # looping to store tokenized words into array
        if( res[i][0] in exceptionList ):
            return x

        else:
            arr_Val.append(res[i][0])
            #print(res)

    for i in range( len(res) ):             # checking the POS as proper Noun (NNP)
        if( res[i][1]=='NNP'):
            length=len(res[i][0])
            arr_Val[i]=str(length*'X' )
    return(' '.join(arr_Val))               # returning the string


def phone_number(inp):           
    regex = r'^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?\s*$'
    return inp.str.replace(regex, 'X' * random.randrange(3, 8))

def address(inp):            
    temp=inp
    parser = CommonRegex()
    inp = inp.apply(parser.street_addresses).str.join(', ')
    return np.where(inp.apply(parser.street_addresses).str.len() == 0, temp, 'X' * random.randrange(3, 8)) 

def checkPHI(df):
myList = df.columns.tolist()   
for x in myList:
    df[x] = df[x].astype(str).apply(name)
    df[x] = phone_number(df[x].astype(str))
    df[x] = address(df[x].astype(str))
```

here I am able to pass each column of a dataframe but instead, I want to pass complete row instead of column

as for now first row is masked as per the function but if the second row NAME column is not masked then it should break and not move to other column  and start from third row

here is what i get the output

```
     Name      |  Number   |  Code     |  
     ...................................
     XXXX      | XXXXXXX   |       0   |
     Health    | XXXXXXX   | XXXXXXXXX | 
     XXXXX     |           | XXXXXXXXX |
     XXXXX     | XXXXXXX   | XXXXXXXXX | 
     XXXXX     | XXXXXXX   | XXXXXXXXXX|
```

here is what i am expecting

```
     Name      |  Number   |  Code     |  
     ...................................
     XXXX      | XXXXXXX   |       0   |
     Health    | 9865432198| 4365719234| 
     XXXXX     |           | XXXXXXXXX |
     XXXXX     | XXXXXXX   | XXXXXXXXX | 
     XXXXX     | XXXXXXX   | XXXXXXXXXX|
```

Comment: `df.apply(func, axis=1)`?

Comment: Can you post a short list of current output and below it expected output, this help me better formulate an answer

Comment: hey @ oppressionslayer updated my question